# retrieve vmware snapshot from copied virtual disk

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware, snapshot

I created ubuntu vmware virtual machine in windows 7. I created its virtual hard disk (vmdk) on an external hard disk. I took some snapshots in due time. I've burnt my laptop recently and I'm happy that at least I got  the virtual hard disk on the external hard drive. Now when I created a new ubuntu virtual machine (ubuntu not yet installed) on an another system and hooked the previous virtual hard disk to it, it takes me to the first snapshot instead of to the latest one. snapshots manager is showing no snapshots! How can I retrieve my snapshots? Are the snapshots lost in my burnt laptop where the virtual machine is created?

Answer (score 0):

Snapshots are stored in a different file from the disk images. For example:

**If** `virtual_machine.vmdk` was the 1st virtual disk and is stored on the datastore 1, *then* `virtual_machine-000001.vmdk` will be the delta file and stored on datastore 1.

If you have the delta file, you should choose to Go To or Revert to it as [explained by VMware](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_preserve_sshot_revert_or_goto.html).